# How can I write my own Python equivalent of stack push and pop functions without using a stack or queue?

Tags: python, linux, stack, queue

I'm using Linux and Python.  I don't want to use os.system to accomplish this nor do I want to use the built-in stack or queue functions.

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service; what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I'm trying to learn more about how Python works.  I'm good with Bash.  I just want to write my own stack push and pop.  Can I just get enough help to get started with my requirements of no using os.system or an existing push/pop command?

Comment: Well do you know how a stack works, generally? Have you looked into [Python's data structures](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) for something that could be used in a similar way? What do you mean *"an existing push/pop command"* - a `list` has `pop`, but isn't a `Queue`, is that acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `list` for queue and stack:

**Stack:** (FILO)

```
>>> st = list()
>>> st.append(1)
>>> st
[1]
>>> st.append(2)
>>> st
[1, 2]
>>> st.pop() # it removes the last element (i.e. the newest element in the list)
2 
>>> st
[1]
```

**Queue:** (FIFO) - pop the first element in the list

```
>>> que = list()
>>> que.append(1)
>>> que
[1]
>>> que.append(2)
>>> que
[1, 2]
>>> que.pop(0)  # we pass in index 0 to remove the earliest element in the list 
1 
>>> que
[2]
```

Please note that the performance of `pop(0)` is bad, since `list()` is not designed for using it as a queue. Use a built-in `collections.deque()` is prefered